# update state with AsyncStorage - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a small problem with componentWillMount when I want to update the component's state I get this error.

[image]

the code is this :

```
export default class RouterComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLogin: null
    }
}

componentWillMount = async () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyUserFireBase:key').then(response => {
        this.setState({ 'isLogin': true });
    }).done();
}



render() {

    return (
        <Router>
            <Stack key="root" hideNavBar>
                <Stack key="main">
                    <Scene key="login" initial={!this.state.isLogin} component={LoginForm} title="Login" />
                    <Scene key="employeeList" initial={this.state.isLogin} component={EmployeeList} title="Employee List" />
                </Stack>
            </Stack>
        </Router >
    )
}
```

}

I have more than 3 days looking for the solution and I can not find it. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out component lifecycle methods to help you with your problem: https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1

For my answer, try this:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyUserFireBase:key').then(response => {
        this.setState({ 'isLogin': true });
    }).done();
}
```

Also, if that does not work, try `Update` instead, since you are setting the state:

```
componentDidUpdate() =  {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyUserFireBase:key').then(response => {
            this.setState({ 'isLogin': true });
        }).done();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `componentDidMount()` instead of `componentWillMount()` and remove `async()`

```
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyUserFireBase:key').then(response => {
        this.setState({ 'isLogin': true });
    }).done();
}
```

componentWillMount is also marked as deprecated in React 16.3
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html (Lifecycle section)